# fixed positioned box inside fixed positioned box scrolls with content

Tags: css

I have a fixed positioned div, which has a scrollable content, inside this div I want to define an another fixed positioned div, which should not scroll with the parent content. How can I do it with css?

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.child {
    left: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent fixed">
    <h1>Parent fixed</h1>
    <div class="child fixed">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        
    </ul>
    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbvarga/chqe7omb/

I expect that the yellow div should be fixed to the browser window, irrespectively of the scroll position.

Many places I can read that fixed positioning means relative to the browser window, but it's not true, because if I scroll the parent div, the position of the fixed child will be different.

I know If I make the two fixed siblings, than it works, so the question is, how can I make it work if the two fixed in a parent-child relationship.

**Update**

I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10 Chrome 42, and here's an anim gif what I see when scrolling : [image]

Don't know what to say, I'm very sad.

Comment: Viewing jsfiddle in firefox <div class="child fixed"> stays at the same position when content scrolled. So it is hard to understand what is wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do whatever it is you are trying to do using `position:fixed` but it's really unclear what it is you are doing.

Comment: @SergiyT. in chrome it scrolls,

Comment: @Paulie_D check the jsfiddle in firefox / safari, and you'll see what I would like to do.

Comment: @balazs Looks the same to me in FF/Safari 5 and Chrome on W7...the yellow div is fixed and doesn't scroll ...the list does. Still not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @balazs Checked in Chrome. Works like in Firefox. Also checked in IE11 - the same as in Firefox. OS - windows 7

Comment: Thanks for checking it in many browsers, than the real question: why is it bad in my Mac. :( I'm a bit desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug in chrome, see details here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490141